# Error while connecting Custom domain to firebase hosting with domain.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I purchased a domain from domain.com, followed the steps of firebase custom domain connect up to second point (Verify ownership). I added the TXT record as described.

Verified with `dig -t txt +noall +answer my-domain.com` and the response holds 2 records:

```
my-domain.com.      3455    IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:66.96.128.0/18 ?all"
```

and

```
my-domain.com.      3455    IN  TXT "google-site-verification=verification code"
```

The Firebase console keeps alerting

> We couldn't verify your domain my-domain.com. Please check your settings and try again.

What could be the possible error & what can I try next?

Comment: That second record seems good. Did you wait for at least an hour (the TTL you specify)? If so, it might be a good time to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen waiting did the trick, thank you.